# nginx. Deny two points anywhere in URL

Tags: nginx

I need configured nginx server, that him show 403-page if URL it contains two points (..) anywhere in URL. Example, if URL is "site.sit/index.php?log=../conf.php - web-server should detect an attempt to go to the directory above and bring in 403-messege. 
I tried configed this idea in conf-file nginx there:

```
location \.\. {
    deny all;
    }
```

But this not work.

Tell me, how do I implement this plan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `location` directive only looks at the *normalized* URI to the left of the `?` - so it will miss any `..` sequence in the arguments.

If you need to check the raw URI being submitted to the server (including arguments), use a regular expression on the `$request_uri` instead.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ \.\.) { return 403; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` directive.

Comment: It's also possible to check only the arguments using `$args` for the full query string or `$arg_name` for a single argument.